# Why MSSQL does not return data to CherryPy?

Tags: python, mysql, cherrypy, pymssql

this is my code:

...

```
CDN_XL = Database('mssql', CDN_XL_HOST, CDN_XL_PORT, CDN_XL_NAME, CDN_XL_USER, CDN_XL_PASS)
```

...

```
def GET(self):
    user = USER
    if user is None:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(401, "NOT_AUTHORIZED")
    with CDN_XL:
        CDN_XL.execute("""Select TrN_DokumentObcy, TrN_NettoR, ToPay, trn_data, trp_termin, data_roz, b_1, b_3, b_4, b_7, b_8, b_9 from(Select DISTINCT TrN_DokumentObcy, TrN_NettoR, SUM(TrP_Pozostaje) as ToPay, DATEADD(day, TrN_Data2, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120)) as trn_data, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120)) trp_termin, DATEADD(day, TrN_DataRoz, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120)) as data_roz, DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_1, DATEADD(day, 3, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_3, DATEADD(day, 4, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_4, DATEADD(day, 7, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_7, DATEADD(day, 8, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_8, DATEADD(day, 9, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_9, DATEADD(day, 10, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_10, DATEADD(day, 14, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_14, DATEADD(day, 15, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_15, DATEADD(day, 22, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_22, DATEADD(day, 23, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_23, DATEADD(day, 40, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_40, DATEADD(day, 41, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_41, DATEADD(day, 70, DATEADD(day, TrP_Termin, CONVERT(date, '1800-12-28', 120))) as b_70 FROM CDN.TraNag, CDN.TraPlat where (TrN_DokumentObcy LIKE 'FS-%' OR TrN_DokumentObcy LIKE 'FSK-%') AND TrN_DokumentObcy NOT LIKE '%/R/%' AND TrN_DokumentObcy NOT LIKE '%/ORG/%' AND TrN_DokumentObcy NOT LIKE '%/CPW/%' AND TrN_DokumentObcy NOT LIKE '%/MC/%' AND TrN_DokumentObcy NOT LIKE '%/INST/%' AND TrN_DokumentObcy <> '' AND TrN_GIDTyp = TrP_GIDTyp and TrN_GIDNumer=trp_gidnumer GROUP BY TrN_DokumentObcy, TrN_Data2, TrN_NettoR, TrN_DataRoz, TrP_Termin) as x Where trn_data >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-2,0) AND trn_data < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0);""")
        CDN_XL.conn.commit()
        logging.debug(CDN_XL.cur.rowcount)
        types = CDN_XL.cur.fetchall()
        information_json = []
    if types is not None and len(types) > 0:

        for typ in types:
            information_json.append({"numberFactures": str(typ["FactureNumbers"]), "sum": str(typ["SumNetto"])})

        output_json = {"payment_list":information_json}
        return json.dumps(output_json, ensure_ascii=False)
    else:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(404, "NOT FOUND")
```

This part

```
logging.debug(CDN_XL.cur.rowcount)
```

return -1

POSTMAN return this:

```
{"payment_list": [{"sum": "None", "numberFactures": "0"}]}
```

DBeaver return this:
[image]

If I use different query exp. "SELECT A, B FROM X" It works, so why in Dbeavear this query work but when I want to pass to CherryPy and use POSTMAN it dosen't. I really don't understand that

Comment: What is CDN_XL? I've never seen a `commit()` on a SELECT query, and the cursor is typically an attribute of the connection

Comment: I suggest you using SQLAlchemy, it has easier to use higher-level API. Also, This question is not really related to CherryPy, but to some misuse of the DB access library.
You're asking to debug your SQL query without actually providing any useful information related to it. What is DB structure for example?